# An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5567

Tags: infopath, form

I am new to sharepoint and infopath. I am trying to explore how it works. I was able to upload succesfully the form i created in infopath to sharepoint. But now that it was all filled up and and clicking the submit button, it won't submit having this error:

> An error occurred while accessing a Web Service. For more information, contact the site administrator.
>     An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
>     Log ID:5567Correlation ID:3568b69c-e016-1000-8399-a5ee00201ce5

Comment: You can check the logs at  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS and check for the given Correlation ID

Comment: What will i do with the correlation id?

Comment: You can search the log file with the guid given in correlationid

Comment: There's no LOG here, only BIN

Comment: are you using sharpoint 2013?

Comment: yes I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: then check  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS i.e in 15 hive

Comment: Hi have you solved this problem? I've encountered the same question as you. Could give some advice?